# Is there a neutral LCA comparing wood to composite materials?

Tags: plastic, wood

I have seen competing information about whether it's a more sound environmental choice to choose real wood or composite decking materials.  Different conclusions are drawn depending on whether the study was backed by a wood industry or plastic industry group.  Big surprise there.

Is anyone aware of a trustworthy comparison between wood decking and composite decking?  I am actually most curious in using the materials for exterior trim, but it appears that decking is a more commonly-covered subject.

Comment: I found a few references that may address this question. Hopefully someone with a bit more time and a better understanding of the topic can take these and write an answer: Peer-reviewed articles from Germany: [1](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.resconrec.2016.10.012), [2](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00107-015-0953-6). From the U.S. Forest Products Lab: [1](https://www.fpl.fs.fed.us/documnts/pdf2014/fpl_2014_bergman007.pdf), [2](https://www.fs.usda.gov/treesearch/pubs/44001). [Peer-reviewed article from an environmental consultant in the U.S.](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jclepro.2010.12.004)